# Preview.app custom keyboard shortcuts broken after Yosemite upgrade

Tags: keyboard, preview

While running Mavericks, I added `Control-P` and `Control-N` as shortcuts for Preview.app.  Sort of Emacs-like page turning.  It worked fine.

After upgrading to Yosemite, these keyboard shortcuts no longer work.  Deleting them from the Shortcuts list in System Preferences and creating them again does not fix the issue.  As you can see in the second screenshot, the shortcuts `^N` and `^P` do not appear in Preview.app's "Go" menu.  I seem to remember that when the shortcuts did work, the "Go" menu showed them.

If there is a shortcut conflict, I haven't been able to find it.  Thanks!

[image: custom shortcuts]

[image: Preview menu]

Comment: Sorry.  I don't mean that the screenshot shows the conflict.  The screenshot only shows that the new keyboard shortcuts are unknown to Preview.app.  I also mean to say there may be a hidden conflict with ^P and ^N that prevents these key combinations from being used for Previous Item and Next Item.  Does this clear up my question?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Had a brain cramp